# Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result()

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

My Model error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result()

```
     <?php
     defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

     class teacher_feedback extends CI_Model {

     public function teacher_feedback_query($teacher)
      {
    $teacher_feedback_query = 'SELECT TD.name, TD.subject, TFA.answer_value,    SBI.first_name, TFSAC.comment, TFSC.comment, TFQ.teachers_feedback_question_id FROM teacher_details as TD inner join teachers_feedback_student_answer as TFSA on TFSA.teacher_id = TD.teacher_id inner join  teachers_feedback_answer as TFA on TFA.teachers_feedback_answer_id = TFSA.teachers_feedback_answer_id inner join teachers_feedback_student_answer_comment as TFSAC on TFSAC.teacher_id = TD.teacher_id inner join student_basic_info as SBI on SBI.student_id=TFSAC.student_id inner join teachers_feedback_student_comment as TFSC on TFSC.student_id = SBI.student_id inner join teachers_feedback_question as TFQ on TFQ.teachers_feedback_question_id = TFSA.teachers_feedback_question_id  where TD.teacher_id = ?';

$teacher_query = $this->db->query($teacher_feedback_query,array($teacher));
$teacher_feedback_result = $this->db->result($teacher_query);
return $teacher_feedback_result();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: If you working on Codeigniter(CI) make sure your Model extends CI_Model. Your question is not clear enough, show your full model so that we can assist you quickly.

Comment: Full model is given

Answer (score 1):

Try Returning result_array() instead of just result()

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do here is wrong. `result` method should be called to the query result and not on the `db` object.

Try this:

```php
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class teacher_feedback extends CI_Model {

     public function teacher_feedback_query($teacher)
     {
          $teacher_feedback_query = 'SELECT TD.name, TD.subject, TFA.answer_value,    SBI.first_name, TFSAC.comment, TFSC.comment, TFQ.teachers_feedback_question_id FROM teacher_details as TD inner join teachers_feedback_student_answer as TFSA on TFSA.teacher_id = TD.teacher_id inner join  teachers_feedback_answer as TFA on TFA.teachers_feedback_answer_id = TFSA.teachers_feedback_answer_id inner join teachers_feedback_student_answer_comment as TFSAC on TFSAC.teacher_id = TD.teacher_id inner join student_basic_info as SBI on SBI.student_id=TFSAC.student_id inner join teachers_feedback_student_comment as TFSC on TFSC.student_id = SBI.student_id inner join teachers_feedback_question as TFQ on TFQ.teachers_feedback_question_id = TFSA.teachers_feedback_question_id  where TD.teacher_id = ?';

          $teacher_query = $this->db->query($teacher_feedback_query,array($teacher));
          //$teacher_feedback_result = $this->db->result($teacher_query);
          $teacher_feedback_result = $teacher_query->result();
          return $teacher_feedback_result; // Remove parenthesis, $teacher_feedback_result is not a function
     }
}

?>
```

**EDIT:**

About the error **Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result()**

PHP throws this error because CodeIgniter MySQLi adapter class does not have a method `result`. Here is the CodeIgniter MySQLi driver class. You can check it, there is no such method `result`:

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

So, when you are calling `$this->db->result($teacher_query)`, `$this->db` is attached to `CI_DB_mysqli_driver` and thus you get an error that you’re calling an undefined method.

Comment: Thank you, but can u explain me what was the exact error

Comment: It's because the CI MySQLi driver does not have a `result` method. Check my edit notes.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time these type of error comes because of we apply core php code on it and ci have its own way to apply this.
So sometimes we succeed to apply some core code but sometimes not. 
In that case, try to go on ci doc you most probably find your solution.
Good luck.